# How to disable automatic function docstring generation in Spyder?

Tags: spyder

Spyder (the Python IDE) generates a function docstring automatically when you click `Enter` after the first line of the function def. How can one disable this feature?

I've looked around in Tools (for instance in `Tools -> Preferences -> Editor`) and did not find a way to do it. But there are tons of features in Spyder so maybe I'm missing it.

Comment: It'd be great if someone had a good answer. Reading the tracker where the guy built it doesn't tell me how to turn it off.  It's not on in my regular instance of Spyder 4, but in the new project environment it is, and it's wasted 45 minutes of my time and loads of frustration trying to make it GO AWAY already. >:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you type in the triple quotes, an icon will pop up that says `Generate docstring`. When this happens, *do not hit `Enter`*. Just hit `esc`.

Until we can just deactivate it in settings, that's what I've been doing.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an anaconda install with kited running in the background? Opening task manager and stopping this from running fixed the problem for me.

Edit: This may be incorrect

Comment: I think this is a spyder-specific feature not connected to kite (I typically don't activate kite): https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/pull/8700